# Why are setup windows called "wizard"?

Tags: etymology

Commonly, the word "wizard" means "someone who practices magic; a sorcerer or magician." [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wizard)

In software wizard is "an user interface type that presents an user with a sequence of dialog boxes that lead the user through a series of well-defined steps" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software))

These two things seem not related at all to me, so I wonder why "wizard" was used and not any other word?

Comment: Because someone at Microsoft decided to call them that.  Like many Microsoft terms, this is not particularly apt. Perhaps "guide" or "guided procedure" might have made more sense. Anyway, just live with it.

Comment: "If implemented correctly, wizards can really do some magic for your users and make them happier and satisfied" -- *Silverlight 4 User Interface Cookbook*.

Comment: Over the years, I have noticed that Microsoft has co-opted words strongly associated with their competition. I don't know whether they are consciously trying disrupt the association or simply piggybacking on it -- maybe both.  http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?story=Software_Wizard.txt

Comment: I seem to remember reading in a Microsoft publication (MSDN News?) a _long_ time ago, when the term was new, that the idea was the wizard was 'the guy down the hall, who always knows what to do' - ie a wizard, compared to the rest of us. The software 'wizard' was intended to encapsulate his knowledge; and it had a slightly stronger meaning than the Wikipedia ref above - it was to guide the user through an _especially difficult_ operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see the second meaning of **wizard** in [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wizard)(same link you have given) it is:

- A skilled or clever person.
- a person who is outstandingly clever in some specified field; expert.

So here *'wizard'* meaning is similar to *'expert'*. And the same [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_(software)) says:

> an [expert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) guides a user through a series of (usually yes/no) questions to solve a problem.

It also states:

> The *Microsoft Manual of Style for Technical Publications* (Version 3.0) urges technical writers to refer to these assistants as "wizards" ...

So the **wizard**/**expert** asks you a series of questions to figure out what you want, and then they use their "expertise" to generate a result.

'Assistant' can be use instead of 'wizard'.

Related: [Why are wizard dialogs called “wizards”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/896344/4248931)